# Symplectic integration of PDE

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, numerics

I consider ordinary wave equation
$$ u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 $$ 
with initial conditions
$$u(x, 0) = \exp (-2 x^2) \\
u_t(x, 0) = 0 $$

To solve this problem I approximate $u_{xx}$ with 4-th order difference scheme and find time evolution with symplectic 4-th order method.

I use following parameters:
$$x_{min} = -500 \\
x_{max} = 500 \\
dx = 0.5 \\
dt = 0.1 $$

The problem is that, for example, in the point $x=0$ this algorithm perfectly works for $t < 1000$ (note that this value equals $x_{max} - x_{min} = 2 x_{max}$ But then evolution looks quite strange. Here is a picture of this.

[image]

I tried to fix boundary value manually (at every step set $u(x_{min}, t) = u(x_{max}, t) = 0, \ u_t (x_{min}, t) = u_t (x_{max}, t) = 0 $ )
and also tried to use "exponential suppression" to avoid radiation from boundaries. 
The $u_{xx}$ approximation with finite difference is used only for points which are more than 2 steps distant from boundaries to avoid problems.

It seems that the problem lies in the presence of boundaries, because such symplectic algorithm works fine for harmonic oscillator (where there are no boundaries) for any time value.

**UPD:** The stencil I use for partial derivative:
$$u_{xx} (x) = \frac{-u(x-2) + 16 u(x-1) - 30 u(x) + 16 u(x+1) - u(x+2)}{12 (dx)^2} $$

Comment: Could you write down the fourth order stencil you are using and how exactly you are imposing the BC? Simply setting the  values to zero in each time step does not sound right but may be I misunderstand what you do.

Comment: have you tried smaller stepsizes? or a simple 'implicit Euler scheme'?

Comment: You use a CFL number of 0.2. Is this small enough for an RK4 integrator?

Comment: @DanielRuprecht , I wrote a stencil. I impose BC with setting values to zero at each time step, why does this not sound right? Also I use exponential suppression - tending all values to zero nearby the boundaries.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth , I don't know exactly values, but I hope so. Moreover, I tried different sets of stepsizes.As you see, evolution goes right way, but looks like boundaries cause such problems that I have.

Comment: @Jan yes, I tried

Comment: My reason to wonder is that technically your BC only says u(x) = 0 (in your stencil). Setting u(x+1) = u(x+2) = 0 also implies a zero derivative at the boundary, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but what's the problem? It corresponds to trivial solution near the boundary, so I don't see where problems may come from.

Comment: @newt Because you're then solving a *different* equation (one where the solution is not only zero at the boundary, but is even flat). And since you're now prescribing *two* boundary conditions where one would already uniquely specify the solution, your problem becomes ill-posed -- either there's no solution (in which case you shouldn't be surprised if trying to compute it blows up at some point), or it's horribly unstable (meaning numerical noise gets amplified rapidly). High-order stencils need to be adapted next to the boundary.